# SQL Server - Best way to use case inside case

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to update the column to find out the unequal data from two tables. I'm using a case query to check both tables, and it's working fine but some conditions must be met which confuses me

**Problem**

I have to use case inside case conditions to check data in column to continue the query command

```
UPDATE a
SET a.IS_ACTIVE =  CASE
                      WHEN
                         a.CODE <> b.CODE OR
                         a.YEAR <> b.YEAR_POSITION OR
                         a.MONTH <> b.MONTH_POSITION OR
                         CASE WHEN a.TYPE = 1 THEN a.AMOUNT <> b.TOTAL_D OR
                         CASE WHEN a.TYPE = 2 THEN a.AMOUNT <> b.TOTAL_K
                         THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                   END        
FROM SEA a INNER JOIN MOUNT b
ON a.CODE = b.CODE AND 
   a.YEAR = b.YEAR_POSITION AND
   a.MONTH = b.MONTH_POSITION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have to use case inside case conditions* No you don't. You are over-complicating your logic. And "Best" is never a good qualifier to include when your code has syntax errors. So let's start with something that is correct.

Notice the conditions in your JOIN. Does it make any sense to include the opposite conditions in your CASE expression? With the join, those first three comparisons will never be TRUE, so why do you include them?

This is how I would write your query. I split the logic for setting the column to 1 into two different search conditions since it is clear and it is easily maintained. It does not need to be split but my experience is that things like this evolve over time.

```
UPDATE a
SET IS_ACTIVE = CASE 
    WHEN a.TYPE = 1 and a.AMOUNT <> b.TOTAL_D THEN 1 
    WHEN a.TYPE = 2 and a.AMOUNT <> b.TOTAL_K THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END 
FROM dbo.SEA a INNER JOIN dbo.MOUNT b
ON a.CODE = b.CODE AND 
   a.YEAR = b.YEAR_POSITION AND
   a.MONTH = b.MONTH_POSITION;
```

I also added a schema name to your tables and a statement terminator - both best practices. I assumed dbo was the correct schema - adjust for your situation. I'm not a fan of single character aliases generally, especially when those letters have little obvious relevance to the table names. That's more of a style concern though it does make a "readability" difference in longer, more complicated queries.

Comment: I just realize. Thanks, very helpful!!